# Choosing confidence interval for hypothesis testing

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

"Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ is a sample on $N(\mu, \sigma)$ where $\sigma$ is known. You want to test the null hypothesis $H_0: \mu = 2$ against $H_1 : \mu < 2$ by using a suitable confidence interval. Which of the following confidence intervals should be used?

$A: I_{\mu} = (-\infty, \bar{x}+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \lambda_{\alpha})$

$B: I_{\mu} = (-\infty, \bar{x}+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \lambda_{\frac{\alpha}{2}})$

$C: I_{\mu} = (\bar{x}+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \lambda_{\alpha}, \infty)$

$D: I_{\mu} = (\bar{x}+\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot \lambda_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}, \infty)$
"

I don't really know where to start here, haven't been able to find any good resource on how to choose interval for hypothesis testing. Some hints on how to tackle this, and similar, problems would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- You are considering whether an observed sample mean might be judged an *extreme* observation if the null hypothesis is true; if it is too extreme, you might reject the null hypothesis.
- The alternative hypothesis gives an indication of which direction(s) count(s) as extreme in the sense of pointing away from the null hypothesis and towards the alternative hypothesis

  - Given the alternative hypothesis in the question, would you think a high sample mean would be seen as extreme? A low sample mean? Both?
- The reverse approach of using confidence intervals produces similar results, in the sense that if the hypothesised population mean is in the confidence interval, this might be seen as a reason for not rejecting the null hypothesis

  - Given the alternative hypothesis, which of the confidence intervals would lead to the rejection of the null hypothesis when the sample mean is extreme in the same direction(s) as before
  - If the null hypothesis is true, which of the confidence intervals lead to the rejection of the null hypothesis with probability $\alpha$?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I want to prove that $\mu < 2$ so I would guess I want the "starting" (lowest?) point of the interval to be the lowest possible, right? Hence $-\infty$. And I want to use $\lambda_{\alpha}$ and not $\lambda{\frac{\alpha}{2}}$ since a smaller $\alpha$ gives a higher value?

Comment: @gbgult - if your alternative hypothesis is $\mu \lt 2$ then low values of the sample mean are seen as extreme.  So when the sample mean is very low, you want your  confidence interval to not include the value $2$; as you say this means using A or B. You want to use A so the probability under the null hypothesis of being in the confidence interval is $1-\alpha$, though if $\lambda_{\alpha}$ is negative then there might be a sign typo in the question

Comment: Thanks again! I don't completely understand what you mean with "You want to use A so the probability under the null hypothesis of being in the confidence interval is 1−". Is it possible to give a more elaborate explanation of that part?

Comment: @gbgult Frequentist hypothesis testing says things like *"if the null hypothesis is true then the probability of seeing this result or a more extreme result is less than $\alpha=5\%$ so this result is statistically significant at the $5\%$ level, leading to rejection of the null hypothesis"*.  Meanwhile frequentist confidence intervals are constructed on the basis of something like *"if I repeated this confidence interval procedure a large number of times, then I would expect about $1-\alpha = 95\%$ of such intervals to cover the true parameter"*.

Comment: Ah! So if I used $\frac{\alpha}{2}$ I would say that I expect about $1 - \frac{\alpha}{2} = 97.5%$ (if I use the same numbers as you) to cover the true parameter, i.e. the intervals would be bigger? I.e. the null hypothesis would more often be in the interval?

Comment: Yes.  Meanwhile, if the alternative hypothesis had instead been $\mu \not 2$ you would have confidence intervals with $\frac{\alpha}2$ at each end, adding up to $\alpha$